# Insert timestamp with JdbcTemplate in Oracle database ( ORA-01858 )

Tags: oracle, date, jdbc, timestamp, jdbctemplate

I've read a lot of stuff about this error, and still not found the mistake.

I'm using JdbcTemplate to insert a row in some table with some timestamp column 
I'm pretty sure the timestamp is the problem, as if delete from the insert it works fine)

My code:

```
        private static final String INSERT_CITAS = "INSERT INTO CITAS (" 
        + "idCita, idServicio, " + "fechaCita, "
        + "idEstado, idUsuarioInicial) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        Object[] params = {
                idCita,
                citaQuenda.getIdServicio(),
                getDateToDBFormat(citaQuenda.getFechaCita()),
                ESTADO_INICIAL,
                USUARIO_INICIAL };

        String queryCitas = INSERT_CITAS;

        super.getJdbcTemplate().update(queryCitas, params);


        protected String getDateToDBFormat(Date fechaCreacion){
        return  "TO_TIMESTAMP('" + 
                    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(fechaCreacion)
                    + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')" ;
        }
```

And having the next error:

```
    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO citas_55 (idCita, idServicio, fechaCita, idEstado, idUsuarioInicial) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];
    ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

I've tried to execute the sql in some SQL editor having success, so I can't be more confused.

Being my params: [461, 100, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-28 00:00:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 8888]  This actually works.

```
    INSERT INTO citas (idCita, idServicio, fechaCita, idEstado, idUsuarioInicial) VALUES (457, 100, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-28 00:00:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') , 1, 8888);
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the template, but is the update using the table metadata to decide what kind of parameter to set - so it'll try to `setTimestamp()` with your string value, possibly introducing implicit conversions?

Comment: A DATE type and a TIMESTAMP type are different.  Your example shows TO_DATE and TO_TIMESTAMP, pleases show the table definition.

Comment: Just a tipo, but both actually works...

Comment: [The docs say](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) "leaving it to the PreparedStatement to guess the corresponding SQL type", so maybe not quite as wild a guess as I thought... so yes, why not pass it as a timestamp?

Comment: Thanks Alex, you were right too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't convert back and forth between dates/timestamps and Strings.

Just pass a `java.sql.Timestamp` instance as a parameter:

```
Object[] params = {
         idCita,
         citaQuenda.getIdServicio(),
         new java.sql.Timestamp(citaQuenda.getFechaCita()),
         ESTADO_INICIAL,
         USUARIO_INICIAL };

String queryCitas = INSERT_CITAS;
super.getJdbcTemplate().update(queryCitas, params);
```

Answer (score 3):

I will go out on a limb here, and think I may see the problem. getDateToDBFormat() method is returning a String type, which contains the text, "TO_TIMESTAMP(...)".  That is not a date or timestamp parameter.  It is a string parameter.  You need to do this instead:

1. Remove the TO_TIMESTAMP stuff from getDateToDBFormat() and have it just return the formatted DATE/TIME value (the format you show is not an oracle timestamp, but a DATE type).
2. change your insert to:

   ```
   "INSERT INTO CITAS ... VALUES (?, ?, TO_DATE(?,?) , ?, ?)"
   ```

Where the parameters to the TO_DATE call are the return from getDateToDBFormat() and the second parameter is the date format mask. However, can't you just get rid of that mess and bind a Java Date type (or jdbc sql equivalent) directly?

That should work.